# C++ Qt Using Quicksort to sort strings alphabetical

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

I want to sort my strings in a trhead but my programm keeps crashing without a usefull message.

```
   void FarmSortWorker::processSort()
    {
    // FramContainer *park =& farm_container[i];
    //park->setFarmName("test");
        QMutex mutex;
        mutex.lock();
        quicksort(2, 4);

        mutex.unlock();
        emit finished();
    }

    void FarmSortWorker::quicksort(int leftIdx, int rightIdx)
    {
        if (leftIdx >= 0 && leftIdx <= farm_container.size() && rightIdx > leftIdx && rightIdx <= farm_container.size())
        {
            if(leftIdx < rightIdx)
            {
                int pivotIdx = divide(leftIdx, rightIdx);
                quicksort(leftIdx, pivotIdx - 1);
                quicksort(pivotIdx + 1, rightIdx);
            }
        }
    }

    void FarmSortWorker::swap(int leftIdx, int rightIdx)
    {
        if (leftIdx >= 0 && leftIdx <= farm_container.size() && rightIdx > leftIdx && rightIdx <= farm_container.size())
        {
            FramContainer temp = farm_container[leftIdx];
            farm_container[leftIdx] = farm_container[rightIdx];
            farm_container[rightIdx] = temp;
        }
    }


    int FarmSortWorker::divide(int leftIdx, int rightIdx)
    {
        int l = leftIdx;
        if (leftIdx >= 0 && leftIdx <= farm_container.size() && rightIdx > leftIdx && rightIdx <= farm_container.size())
        {
            int r = rightIdx - 1;
            int pivot = (int) farm_container[rightIdx].getFarmName().at(0).toLatin1();

            while (l <= r)
            {
                if((int) farm_container[l].getFarmName().at(0).toLatin1() < pivot)
                {
                    ++l;
                }
                else
                {
                    this->swap(l, r);
                    --r;
                }
            }
            this->swap(l, rightIdx);
        }
        return 1;
    }


void FarmSortWorker::processSort()
{
// FramContainer *park =& farm_container[i];
//park->setFarmName("test");
    QMutex mutex;
    mutex.lock();
    quicksort(2, 4);

    mutex.unlock();
    emit finished();
}

void FarmSortWorker::quicksort(int leftIdx, int rightIdx)
{
    if (leftIdx >= 0 && leftIdx <= farm_container.size() && rightIdx > leftIdx && rightIdx <= farm_container.size())
    {
        if(leftIdx < rightIdx)
        {
            int pivotIdx = divide(leftIdx, rightIdx);
            quicksort(leftIdx, pivotIdx - 1);
            quicksort(pivotIdx + 1, rightIdx);
        }
    }
}

void FarmSortWorker::swap(int leftIdx, int rightIdx)
{
    if (leftIdx >= 0 && leftIdx <= farm_container.size() && rightIdx > leftIdx && rightIdx <= farm_container.size())
    {
        FramContainer temp = farm_container[leftIdx];
        farm_container[leftIdx] = farm_container[rightIdx];
        farm_container[rightIdx] = temp;
    }
}


int FarmSortWorker::divide(int leftIdx, int rightIdx)
{
    int l = leftIdx;
    if (leftIdx >= 0 && leftIdx <= farm_container.size() && rightIdx > leftIdx && rightIdx <= farm_container.size())
    {
        int r = rightIdx - 1;
        int pivot = (int) farm_container[rightIdx].getFarmName().at(0).toLatin1();

        while (l <= r)
        {
            if((int) farm_container[l].getFarmName().at(0).toLatin1() < pivot)
            {
                ++l;
            }
            else
            {
                this->swap(l, r);
                --r;
            }
        }
        this->swap(l, rightIdx);
    }
    r

eturn 1;
}
```

farm_container is a QList& and has a size of 900.

How do I debug this correctly or what could the error be.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the message? Have you stepped through it in a debugger?

Comment: I am not C++ pro, but feels that issue here "leftIdx <= farm_container.size()" should be "leftIdx < farm_container.size()"

Comment: Write some Tests with small Lusts. When you find one that crashes, try to reduce the example as much as possible so that the error still occurs. Then try to debug the execution of this example. And if that does not help post the example and the error-description here.

Comment: The program appears for a second and says: the program has crashed.
Not yet because I don't' know where to start..

Comment: The local mutex in `processSort` is kind of pointless. And `<=` should be `<`.

Comment: I chagend <= to < but still no luck

Comment: @user2357505 - can you post the trace? Use GDB to debug.

Comment: The debugger says Exception at 0xd2ff61a, code 0xc000000fd: stack_overflow, flags=0x0(frist chance). It seems like it calls way to often quicksort.

Comment: This code is incomplete - it doesn't actually do any sorting!  Hard to help without a full example.

Comment: @user2357505, your `quicksort()` function is called too many times recursively, so it cause a stack overflow. You can swap recursion with a loop to solve this problem

Comment: My post was edited by Thomas... :( I solved the problem.In my devide function I returned a "1" instead of a "l" so that my pivot element is always 1. Thank you all!!

Comment: @user2357505: In this case you should provide an answer to your question (not in the comments, but a real answer).

Comment: Why don't you just use the `qSort` template function in QtAlgorithms?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a trivial error that was discovered.


Comment: It is not off-topic. It was a stupid mistake but it is not off-topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, in my devide function I returned a "1" instead of a "l" so that my pivot element is always 1.